# How to serve static frontend on cloudflare on main punity.de while managing api.punity.de and later other services on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, amazon-s3, cloudflare, api-gateway

Im really **confused** how to get **this** done.

I want to serve my static react **frontend** serving via cloudflare because of performance reasons on my root domain punity.de, while managing the **backend api** api.punity.de with aws services on aws.

I know **normally** you can just move the whole domain to cloudflare, point there to aws servers, **but** I want to use aws services on backend routing and whole backend technology. So instead I want to have like the api on aws while frontend goes on cloudflare.

its not possible with one domain I think, so I thougth to serve like root domain punity.de on cloudflare, while having punityservices.de on aws or similar domain, like an external domain on aws. But this looks shitty.

I also thougth to serve like the api with api gateway instead of my current application with beanstalk and auto-scaling. On cloudflare I could serve api.punity.de to an cloudfront distrubution which serves the api on api gateway to the nearest user location, also because of costs.

Whats your thougths?

Answer (score 0):

There's no real reason not to use cloudflare on your APIs. It will help mitigate DDoS attacks should you get one. You can onboard your domain into cloudflare and "orange cloud"/proxied mode on the DNS entry for punity.de and "grey cloud"/DNS only mode for the api.punity.de DNS entry and this will do what you want.